# media manager，error not work，thanks！

Tags: media-manager

open the media management，its error “Property 'mime_type' of argument 'item' of event onFetchMediaItems has a wrong item. Valid: string”

i dont know why，thanks！

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enable the `fileinfo` PHP extension, which might need to be done by your hosting provider, if you don't have the necessary permissions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981576/how-to-enable-php-fileinfo-extension-in-php

Comment: thank you very much！！！its working！