# Need help with Media component error

Tags: media-manager

When I go to content > media, I don't see anything and cannot upload images or make folders. There is the error: "Property 'mime_type' of argument 'item' of event onFetchMediaItems has a wrong item. Valid: string".
I found a possible solution could be to enable the fileinfo PHP extension. I did it but it didn't help. Php settings tab (on Joomla System information) says 'Fileinfo Available: No'. So, if it is enabled on cPanel, how to make it available to Joomla?

New update:
I checked with the hosting provider and got this answer: "It is NOT possible to change PHP settings from the php.ini file at the server level. If you need to change the php.ini settings, create your own php.ini file in the directory where the script that requires such changes is located."

I created php.ini file in Joomla root folder, added this line: extension = fileinfo.so

It didn't help.
Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same message last week and enabling `fileinfo` did resolve the issue. Have you confirmed that the` fileinfo` is actually available by going into System Information and then the PHP Information tab of your Joomla installation?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/32569/120

Comment: @NeilRobertson, it's not really a duplicate. That solution didn't help me. I'm posting here for the first time so I don't know if is it custom to follow the rules or not, but when I wanted to comment on that topic, these rules showed up: 
" Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
But avoid … Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers." so I started new topic.

Comment: @Irata when I look at cPanel PHP Selector it looks enabled. In System Information... I'm not sure. Fileinfo is mentioned twice: 
1) in Configure Command  '--enable-fileinfo=shared'  (among others)
2) in SPL > Classes > SplFileInfo (among others)

Comment: In my Joomla 4 under PHP Information  I see a line under the heading "fileinfo" that shows 'fileinfo support  enabled '. The heading is between 'exif' and 'filter'

Comment: I don't have it.  It's Joomla 4.3.4 php 8.1.  I found 'filter' (if that's it - filter / Input Validation and Filtering / enabled) betwin 'dom' and 'ftp'  but not fileinfo nor exif

Comment: @Irata I found it on php settings tab and it says 'Fileinfo Available: No'. So, if it is enabled on cPanel, how to make it available?

Comment: Checking the fileinfo box on PHP Selector is normally all you need to do. I suspect you may another issue to do with your hosting set up that you will probably need to contact your provider about and ask them to help you make fileinfo active on your account.

Comment: I checked with the hosting provider and got this answer: "It is NOT possible to change PHP settings from the php.ini file at the server level. If you need to change the php.ini settings, create your own php.ini file in the directory where the script that requires such changes is located." 

I created php.ini file in Joomla root folder, added this line: extension = fileinfo.so 

It didn't help.

Comment: Who do you host with? Can you create a phpinfo file in your root directory - it may give some insight.